# Whats the inverse of var $removable = $container.find(selector);?

Tags: jquery

Am trying to select all elements that aren't 'selector'.

Something like

```
var $removable = $container.find(.not(selector));
```

But I know the syntax is wrong.
Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var $removable = $container.find(':not('+ selector +')');
```

**OR**

```
var $removable = $container.find('some_selector').not(selector);
```

From [@Mattias comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741852/whats-the-inverse-of-var-removable-container-findselector/11741891#comment15584352_11741891)

```
$container.find('some_selector:not('+selector+')'
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the second example, as the first would potentially need to dig through *all* descendants of `$container`. You want `some_selector` to be sufficiently restrictive, so the set on which the `.not()` clause needs to be executed is relatively small. Note that the second example is equivalent to `$container.find('some_selector:not('+selector+')')`, but the latter uses only one DOM query instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple using the not selector

```
$('div').not('#selector').css('background-color', 'red');​
```

See this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/s5LE7/). The above example assumes that you want to find div elements which are not the element with the id 'selector'.